# Is this sentence correct - "what an ephemeral rendezvous we had"?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence, word-usage

I met some girls last month, and recently I came in contact with one of them. And I really wanted to say something about our first meeting. Can you please tell me if the following sentence is correct and grammatical?

> What an ephemeral rendezvous we had at the hotel.

Comment: Did you really mean [*ephemeral*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ephemeral)? That word is not normally used for single events.

Comment: @St John of the Cross yes... ephemeral is the word.  I used this because I met these girls only for 24hrs.

Comment: *Ephemeral* is wrong, because the word is not used for single events; it's used to describe phases. It would be better to use a word which describes the experience itself, like *enjoyable*; or perhaps *brief but enjoyable*.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross I'm having trouble seeing what you mean. _Ephemeral_ is used for objects, living creatures, and multiple or single events. Your concept that it is restricted to describing phases is simply not true. Additionally, your suggestion of _enjoyable_ to replace _ephemeral_ would be substituting a word that is not even remotely synonymous. I think your comments are entirely off track.

Comment: @JohnM.Landsberg It wasn't intended to be synonymous. But you're right: writing advice is off-topic.

Comment: @StJohnoftheCross maybe "fleeting" would be a better substitute?

Comment: Formally exclamatory sentences beginning with (normally interrogative) *wh-* words are typically written with an exclamation mark at their end. *What a good boy am I! How interesting! What a racket!*

Comment: Perfect grammar. Poor composition. Needs rephrasing. Both *ephemeral* as well as *rendezvous* are inappropriate to the context.

Answer (score 1):

Structurally (that is, grammatically), there seems nothing wrong with the sentence (other than the fact that "what" should be capitalized, and the period should go inside the quotation marks if you're going by American usage.

But "ephemeral" means "fleeting" or "transient," and it carries a strong implication of something delicate and difficult to catch, like the ghost of a butterfly. Is that what you want to say? It's also a bit too unusual and poetic for a casual statement like this; most people wouldn't use it in light conversation.

And perhaps more important, "rendezvous" carries the implication of two people meeting (often secretly) as lovers. I suspect you *really* don't mean *that.*

Comment: I would think encounter was a better choice than rendevouz

Comment: @John M. Landsberg The intent is to impress one of the girl that I spent time intimately.Treat it like a one-liner sentence, so yes if it is poetic then I assume it is justified.

Comment: @user40078 "I would love it if our rendezvous weren't so ephemeral"

Comment: 'Brief Encounter' is one lady I know's favourite film. She's never used up many tissues on 'Ephemeral Rendezvous'.